# Passing attributes to shortcode dynamically

Tags: shortcode, variables

Can I pass dynamically to shortcode attributes like as the following example shows

```
[ authoorsposts  author = get_the_author_id(); ]
```

Comment: Unfortunately does is not possible. Any executable or dinamic code must be handle in the shortcode function as @hans-spieß suggets in his answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not quite like that, but you can achieve the same result if you use a pre-defined value or argument in your shortcode to act as a "flag":

```
[authoorsposts author="post"]
```

...then in your handler:

```
function wpse_209684_author( $atts ) {
    if ( ! empty( $atts['author'] ) ) {
        $author = $atts['author'];

        if ( $author === 'post' ) // Our flag, make $author the current post author
            $author = get_the_author_id();
        else // Otherwise just accept a hardcoded author ID
            $author = absint( $author );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could access the author object inside the [shortcode](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API) function:

```
$author = get_the_author();
//  access ID of author object like $author->ID
```

Since shortcodes are added in the content, your Php code would be escaped and won't execute.